# Timeout Expire on INSERT Query

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

I am trying to insert a row in a table using simple INSERT Query in a transaction. It works fine in SQL Server but I am not able to insert the data using my business object.

I am calling a SELECT query using the Command as:

```
Using cm As New SqlCommand
    With cm
        .Connection = tr.Connection
        .Transaction = tr
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = Some Select Query
        .ExecuteScalar()
         '' Do something

        .CommandText = Insert Query
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
End Using
```

I am getting the Timeout period expired error at ".ExecuteNonQuery()" line.

Any other DML query is running perfectly fine at this point.

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: Can you post more information?  I've got instructions on how to clarify your slow-query question here:

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answsers. However, I have got its solution. I was using nested Sqltransactions in my business objects.

Answer (score 0):

Management Studio has it's connections set to not timeout, which could explain why it works there.  You can do this in your code by setting your connection's `.Timeout` property to 0.  However, this is not recommended unless you *really* mean it.

Instead, we need to figure out what's taking so long.  Does the Management studio query take a long time to finish?  Could it be waiting on a transaction commit?  Can you profile to find out where the app is spending it's time?

Comment: SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout Property is readonly. Also, I have not called the Transaction.Commit(). It will be called after this INSERT Query. Intresting thing is, I have another similar Business Object, where INSERT is executing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your query is using a bad query plan.  Try setting ARITHABORT ON and that should bypass the query plan:

```
Dim arithabortCmd As New SqlCommand("SET ARITHABORT ON", cn)
arithabortCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I would make sure the database indexes are updated by executing this SQL on the database:

```
-- Execute this to rebuild all for a given database. Replace the <databasename> after EXEC.
EXEC <databasename>..sp_MSforeachtable @command1='DBCC DBREINDEX (''*'')', @replacechar='*'
```

Comment: SET ARITHABORT ON does what you say? Reference...?